# How can I remap keys in the minibuffer?

Tags: keymap, minibuffer

I thought I could just use `minibuffer-local-map` but it isn't working.

With `emacs -Q` I eval:

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
```

Then open up `M-:` and hit `C-h c TAB` and it says TAB runs the command completion-at-point. What gives?

What I really want to do is map tab in the minibuffer to `helm-lisp-completion-at-point`. It also would be helpful if I could map it only for `eval-expression` but that's not required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "TAB") nil)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, that still doesn't work.

Comment: Actually never mind, that works if I put `helm-lisp-completion` in place of `nil`. Thanks!

Comment: How can I bind it for `C-h`?